# How to count field with multiple values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a MySQL database and Table1 has a column that can get four distinct values e.g 1,2,3,4. Is it possible to create one query to count 4s and all the other values together?

For example

```
     column1
row1    1
row1    4
row1    2
row1    4
row1    3
```

should produce 2 and 3, two 4s and the rest values.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide better sample data and desired output, as in [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: `and the rest values` -- Eh?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN column1 = 4 THEN '4' ELSE 'other' END,
   COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY 
   CASE WHEN column1 = 4 THEN '4' ELSE 'other' END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),           -- total records count
       SUM(column1),       -- count of records with non-null `column1`
       SUM(column1 = 4),   -- count of records with `column1` = 4
       SUM(column1 != 4)   -- count of records with `column1` other than 4 or NULL
FROM sourcetable
```